# hide navbar when tapped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am making a slideshow for in my app. I want it almost like the photo app of Apple. It is almost finished just some small issues. I want to hide the navbar when tapped on the screen and show it when tapped again. But I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// catch the screen tap and call a method to hide the navigation bar
UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleNavBar:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
[gesture release];

- (void)toggleNavBar:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    BOOL barsHidden = self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden;
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!barsHidden animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: do you know how to make the navbar transparent and 1 more small problem is when the nav bar fades the image scrolls a bit up. Do you know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to hide the navigation bar?  Tapping *in* the navigation bar (which would be quite tricky, if not downright impossible) or via some other button or via another method?

In general, you can definitely hide the navigation bar.

Look at [`[UINavigationController setNavigationBarHidden: animated:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setNavigationBarHidden%3aanimated%3a) (I've linked the Apple documentation)

Comment: I want to hide the navbar when tapped on the screen. Just as in the photo app of iPhone.

Comment: Jano's answer should do what you're looking for, then.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Gesture to Screen using

UITapGestureRecognizer *theSingleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                    initWithTarget:self

action:@selector(handleSingleTapForImage:)];
        [inImageView addGestureRecognizer:theSingleTapGesture];
        [theSingleTapGesture release];

1. In gesture method show or hide NavigationBar

   ```
   -(void)handleSingleTapForImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:![self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden] animated:YES];
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

Make navigation translucent

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```